# Ошибка в js скрипте

Tags: javascript

Вот простой скрипт на js:

```
var _Tools = {
      Sort:
        function (KEY){
            _Products.sort(
                function (l, r){
                    l = l.childNodes[KEY].textContent;
                    r = r.childNodes[KEY].textContent;
                    if(KEY > 4 && KEY < 8)
                        l = +l, r = +r;
                    return (l > r ? 1 : (l < r ? -1 : 0));
                }
            );
            this.SetEvents();
        }
```

Он работает в яндекс браузере и в некоторых версях хрома. Почему?

Какие-то из этих методов не поддерживаются другими браузерами?

Comment: Откройте консоль, посмотрите, на чем валится. Но SetEvents() и textContent вижу впервые (хоть и не js-разработчик)

Comment: Я хорошо знаю js, но SetEvents тоже вижу впервые. Это ваш метод? Может, ошибка там? Т.к. установка обработчиков - одна из вещей, которая до сих пор требует хаков ради кроссбраузерности.